# Good resource to learn geometric interpretations of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, reference-request

I need a good resource to learn **matrices** and all its **properties** through geometry. I feel geometry gives an insight into many matrix operations and a good resource will be useful for many students who wish to get a better insight into matrices.